# Introspecting Android style in code

Tags: android, android-styles

I have a style

```
<style name="MyText">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffff8080</item>
    <item name="android:background">#ffc0c0c0</item>
</style>
```

that I would like to introspect in code.  I run this code:

```
final Resources r = getResources();
final TypedArray a = r.obtainTypedArray(R.style.MyText);
try {
    for (int i=0; i<a.length(); ++i) {
        final TypedValue v = a.peekValue(i);
        if (v != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "assetCookie: " + v.assetCookie);
            Log.d(TAG, "changingConfigurations: " + v.changingConfigurations);
            Log.d(TAG, "data: " + v.data);
            Log.d(TAG, "density: " + v.density);
            Log.d(TAG, "resourceId: " + v.resourceId);
            Log.d(TAG, "string: " + v.string);
            Log.d(TAG, "type: " + v.type);
            Log.d(TAG, "---------------------------------");
        }
    }
} finally {
    a.recycle();
}
```

The output is:

```
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): assetCookie: 2
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): changingConfigurations: 0
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): data: -32640
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): density: 0
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): resourceId: 0
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): string: null
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): type: 28
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): ---------------------------------
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): assetCookie: 2
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): changingConfigurations: 0
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): data: -4144960
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): density: 0
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): resourceId: 0
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): string: null
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): type: 28
D/PlaceholderFragment( 2051): ---------------------------------
```

From the output I know the type of the TypedValue and the value it stores.  I would also be interested to find out which TypedValue is `android:textColor` and which is `android:background`.  How can I do that?

Thank you!